# Holomorphic vector bundle obtained from exceptional divisor has one section.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I've been reading Huybrecht's *Complex Geometry*, and ran across this question in section 2.5:

> If $X$ is a compact complex manifold, and $Y$ a hypersurface, show
>   that $\mathcal{O}(E)$ ( where $E = \sigma^{-1}(Y)$ is the exceptional
>   divisor) has exactly one global section up to scaling.

I suspect this problem is quite simple, yet I frustratingly cannot make much progress on it. There is a hint given that one could consider the case of the blow-up of a point on a Riemann surface, but in this case, since the point is a smooth divisor, $\text{Bl}_Y(X)= \hat X \cong X$. Since in addition $\mathcal{O}(E)|_E \cong \mathcal{O}(-1)$, the obvious candidate for our supposed unique section is the defining function for the divisor (as we must vanish along $E$ as $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ has no sections). Does this line of reasoning hold for higher dimensions (even if $Y$ is not smooth)? I didn't need compactness so I imagine that this is wrong. If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Small remark : when you say $\rm{Bl}_Y(X) \cong X$, it's not true. Blowing-up up a surface will change the surface, even if it is at a smooth point. For example, the blow-up of $\Bbb P^2$ at a point is the projectivized bundle $\Bbb P_{\Bbb P^1} (\mathcal O(1) \oplus \mathcal O)$.

Comment: I should have clarified. I meant one complex dimension, not two. (Edited)

Comment: You have at least one global section cutting out $E$. If there was a second independent section then you should be able to show that its zero locus would intersect $E$ generically transversally, violating negativity of the normal bundle of $E$. Can you make this precise? Alternatively, you could try playing around with basic exact sequences...

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks Tabes for the bit above (even if I am unable to make it precise currently). I'll sketch it here for posterity. $E$ is a hypersurface, and as such is an effective divisor. We know that we can then construct a global section of $\mathcal{O}(E)$ from the cocycles. Using Tabes's comment, this section is unique up to multiplication by a global holomorphic function. Since $X$ is compact, these global holomorphic functions are just scalars. Hence the claim.

Comment: Dear @TabesBridges,can you explain the meaning of "violating negativity of the normal bundle of "?I still can't figure this question out.Can you explain it more explicitly?Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steve the normal bundle of $E$ has negative degree, hence no global sections. While the section cutting out $E$ vanishes along $E$ hence lies in the kernel of the restriction map $\mathcal O(E) \to \mathcal O(E)|_E$, any other section will be linearly independent, hence restricts to a non-trivial section of the restriction, a contradiction.

Comment: Dear@TabesBridges,thanks for your patience and time!